# how safe is object oriented Lua?

Tags: oop, lua

Lua beginner here, i am looking into lua. 
my question is: since an object in Lua is just a table,
new fields can be added at runtime. if I have a typo in the code, and instead of changing a field, I create a new field, won't that bring mayhem? ;)
I would only be able to figure out the bug in runtime, if I even get to that point in the program.
(of course the table concept has other benefits like meta programming without reflection, but my question is about "safety" or predictability.)

Is that the right conclusion?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is correct.
When working with a dynamically typed language, you'll need an extensive suite of unit tests, to make sure you cover all possible scenarios and prevent the kind of mayhem you described.

If you want to protect yourself from this, I'd recommend looking at a static typed language, such as java, c# or scala, and let the compiler do the type-checking for you.

This is why Twitter moved from Ruby to Scala - as the project grows, it gets progressively harder to keep track of bugs that can only be verified at runtime using a dynamically typed language - but could be verified at compile-time by a static language compiler.

---

Dynamic typed languages are based on [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> If it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it is a duck

I prefer [this version](https://twitter.com/slyphon/status/398937654605381632):

> If it walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it’s probably gonna throw exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Lua gives you the mechanisms to have at least as much safety as other dynamic programming languages with baked-in object models do. See [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StrictStructs) for instance.

Errors will still happen at runtime only though, so you need a test suite with decent coverage.

There are projects to add static typing to Lua. Fabien Fleutot, who created metalua, presented his at the latest Lua Workshop. See:

- [his slides](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mfvnzagx2gixdb/luawshop13-fleutot.pptx)
- [a high-level overview of his work](https://github.com/fab13n/metalua/blob/tilo/src/tilo/readme.md)
- [a more formal paper about it](https://github.com/fab13n/metalua/blob/tilo/doc/tilo/paper/tilo.pdf?raw=true)